# GUI на Tkinter и несколько функций с циклами for в отдельном потоке

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, gui, tkinter

Пишу GUI для парсера-постера web сайта на Tkinter. Парсер обрабатывает информацию с web страницы с помощью 2 циклов. Первый цикл проходится по всех страницах сайта и собирает ссылки на нужные товары, проверяет наличие товаров и пишет данные в базу.
Второй цикл проходится по собранных в базу данным. обрабатывает их и постит на другой сайт. Написал функцию в которой постоянно выполняются эти 2 цикла по очереди.

Возникли трудности:
Сделал на форме 2 кнопки. Первая для запуска в отдельном потоке, вторая для остановки этого потока. С запуском все понятно, не знаю прервать выполнения этого потока в не зависимости в котором из циклов он сейчас. Также не знаю как вывести статистику работы циклов в окно Tkinter.

Подскажите пожалуйста как такое сделать.

Добавляю код небольшого примера на Tkinter в котором реализована работа аналогично моему парсеру. Целый код парсера не писал поскольку он большой.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import threading
import queue

import time


# Классы потоков
class ThreadedClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.stop = threading.Event()
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.disable_ui()
        self.start()
        self.periodic_call()

    def check_queue(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                msg = self.queue.get(False)
                self.send_statistic(msg)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

    def queue_put(self, msg_type, msg_text):
        self.queue.put({'type': msg_type, 'send': msg_text})

    def periodic_call(self):
        self.check_queue()
        if self.is_alive():
            self.parent.after(100, self.periodic_call)
        else:
            self.enable_ui()


class FirstParser(ThreadedClient):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def send_statistic(self, msg):
        if msg['type'] == 'status':
            self.parent.status_text.config(text=msg['send'])
        elif msg['type'] == 'count_find':
            self.parent.find_text.config(text=msg['send'])
        elif msg['type'] == 'count_post':
            self.parent.post_text.config(text=msg['send'])
        else:
            pass

    def disable_ui(self):
        self.parent.btn.config(state="disabled")

    def enable_ui(self):
        self.parent.btn.config(state="active")

    def run(self):
        # Здесь код который будеи выполнен при каждом запуске потока
        print('Старт парсинга')
        self.queue_put('status', 'Начинается работа скрипта')
        time.sleep(1)
        while True:
            count_find = []
            for i in range(1, 100):
                # Здесь первый цикл в котором будет выполнятся парсинг (для примера обращение к сайту и парсинг заменил
                # на функцию печати
                self.queue_put('status', 'Идет работа парсера')
                if (i % 5) == 0:
                    print('Парсер:', i)
                    count_find.append(i)
                    self.queue_put('count_find', i)
                    time.sleep(1)
            for i in count_find:
                # Здесь второй цикл в котором будет идти постинг информации полученой в первом цикле (для примера
                # заменил на функцию печати
                self.queue_put('status', 'Идет работа постера')
                if (i % 2) == 0:
                    print('Постер:', i)
                    self.queue_put('count_post', i)
                    time.sleep(1)


# класс Tkinter
class MainForm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.thread = None

        self.btn = None
        self.status_text = None
        self.find_text = None
        self.post_text = None

        self.init_main_form()

    # Настройки окна
    def setup_window(self, title, width, height):
        window = self.master
        window.title(title)
        if width == 0 and height == 0:
            window.geometry(f"+{(window.winfo_screenwidth() - window.winfo_reqwidth()) // 2}"
                            f"+{(window.winfo_screenheight() - window.winfo_reqheight()) // 2}")
        else:
            window.geometry(
                f"{width}x{height}+{(window.winfo_screenwidth() - window.winfo_reqwidth()) // 2 - width // 2}"
                f"+{(window.winfo_screenheight() - window.winfo_reqheight()) // 2 - height // 2}")
        window.resizable(False, False)

    # Создание главного окна
    def init_main_form(self):
        self.setup_window('Главное окно', 800, 400)

        tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self)
        tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
        tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

        tab_control.add(tab1, text='Первый парсер')

        self.btn = ttk.Button(tab1, text='start', command=self.start_thread)
        self.btn.pack()

        btn_stop = ttk.Button(tab1, text='stop', command=self.stop_thread)
        btn_stop.pack()

        self.status_text = tk.Label(tab1, text='Ожидание ...', font=('', 12))
        self.status_text.pack()

        self.find_text = tk.Label(tab1, text='0', font=('', 12))
        self.find_text.pack()

        self.post_text = tk.Label(tab1, text='0', font=('', 12))
        self.post_text.pack()

        tab_control.add(tab2, text='Второй парсер (ещё в планах)')

        tab_control.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    def start_thread(self):
        # Код запуска потока
        self.thread = FirstParser(self)

    def stop_thread(self):
        # Здесь будет код остановки потока
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainForm(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Код покажите пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу